# Matrix with all possible contiguous submatrices - does this problem have a name?

Tags: combinatorics

I thought of the following question out of the blue:

> **Question:** What is the smallest (in terms of number of entries) possible matrix $\mathbf M$ over $\mathbb Z_2$, such that every possible $2 \times 2$  matrix over $\mathbb Z_2$ appears as a *contiguous* submatrix of $\mathbf{M}$?

> **My solution:** First note there is a $5 \times 5$ solution:
> $$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
> So it remains to prove this is minimal. We need $16$ unique
> continguous submatrices, so $\mathbf{M}$ has dimension $n \times m$
> where $(n-1)(m-1) >= 16$. And $n = m = 5$ minimises $nm$ subject to
> this constraint.

I was wondering if this style of problem has a name, and if it produces any interesting mathematics? I'm aware of [superpermutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superpermutation), which seems to have a similar flavour.

This is a relatively boring answer, but there are many possible extensions:

- What happens if we want all $k \times k$ possible binary matrices, for general $k$?
- What about matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for general $n$?
- What if we allow 'wrapping' around the edges of the matrix? (In the $5 \times 5$ solution above, we could remove the final row to obtain a $4 \times 5$ solution with wrapping).

Comment: It’s called a de Bruijn torus, or a de Bruijn array. Here’s one interesting paper, especially for matrices with more than two symbols: https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(93)90087-O

Comment: @MikeEarnest nice one, thank you!